# How can I get TextMate to work with imported files?

Tags: objective-c, macos, import, textmate, file-management

I'm using TextMate to do some Objective-C exercises. When everything is in one file, it works fine, but as soon as I want to work with multiple files it gives an error. For example, I have a separate `Rectangle.h` file to be imported:

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Rectangle *rectangle = [[Rectangle alloc] init];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Running gives this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Rectangle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ccccStDD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm using the C bundle's "Run" command. Using the Xcode bundle's "Build & Run" command gives me a different error.

How can I make TextMate import my `Rectangle.h` file and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a compiler error, but a linker error.
Your import should be fine, as long as it's in the same directory as your main file.

I guess you should also have a `Rectangle.m` file. You need to compile both files (`Rectangle.m` and your main file) as object files (with the `-c` argument), and then link them together to produce an executable.

Or simply compile both files together:

```
gcc -Wall -framework Foundation -o test test.m Rectangle.m
```

Note that if your header files are in a separate directory, you can specify it to GCC using the `-i` or `-I` arguments.

**EDIT:**

I've just seen a mention of Xcode. Are you using Xcode or TextMate?

If you compile using Xcode, and get the error, it's likely that your `Rectangle.m` file is not part of your main Xcode target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All files are in the same directory. I'm using TextMate. I can get this to work easily with Xcode, but since I'm just doing exercises, making a new project for each one is too much. I want to be able to quickly make a change and run it, without dropping out to the Terminal. TextMate lets me run quickly as long as everything is in one file. When I try to import, the error comes.